# Rendering single thing without having to clear entire screen in sdl

Tags: c++, c, sdl, sdl-2

Are there layers to sdl or something?

by layers I mean like in photoshop we have multiple layer and can draw on one without effecting the other,

for example if I had a `main_layer` , a `background_layer` & an `enemy_layer` where the main player reandering (like moving the character by user), a static background rendering & enemies rendering can take place respectively?

instead of having to clear the entire screen then placing **everything** back again over and over? i.e. changing a single thing without effecting the other? can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Interesting. My bet is on "No." but I will follow the question and hope to be proven wrong.

Comment: Would you accept solutions in which each layer has to be cleared and created completely again? For each frame? For each change to that layer? Would you accept solutions which require clearing the screen each frame, but the unchanged layers still exist and can be reused? Would you accept solutions which act exactly as you describe/require but are simply 100 times slower than the usual methods of clearing and rerendering everyhing?

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm not sure I follow, can u provide some reference or example to what you're saying?

Comment: @Yunnosch I actually wanted to know if there is anything prebuilt within SDL itself but if there isn't anything then u can post an answer with an example and if it works I'll mark it as correct

Comment: OK, I will try. Scenario A: You render background into one "layer". You render player into second layer. You render enemy into third layer. You put all three layers on screen. Looks good. Player moves, but neither background nor enemey. You only rerender player into second layer (after clearing it), clear screen, put all three layers to screen and get a frame where player is different everything else is same. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: @Yunnosch I get what you mean, and I think it is acceptable but as mentioned earlier will this solution be "100 slower"? regardless I think u should post an answer

Comment: I just want you to clarfiy whether speed is what you are after. Because I think it is possible but NOT faster. I phrased "100 times slower" in order to provoke you into clarifying this (and a few other possibly overlooked disadvantages, which I will mention after you clarified speed and before making an answer). Or to put it differently, I wanted to make you reconsider your goal, in the light of the concept of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Yunnosch speed is not what I'm after (it's just a bonus if the solution is faster) but I don't see any harm in seeing a practical model of what you've suggesting

Comment: With `SDL_SetRenderTarget()` you can easily create your own layer system. I'll draft an example as an answer.

Comment: @Frank Go ahead (you are obviously further into the technical details than I am). Be wary of "Can player be behind and before enemy?" and "Can I detect collision of enemy and player or bullet and enemy or bullet and player?" and "Is it possible to do this without any clearing of layer or screen?" Those are the follow up questions which I predict here....

Comment: @Yunnosch don't worry I'll try my best not to ask useless follow up questions, I'll figure all that out on my own, i just want to be pointed in the right direction :)

Comment: Thanks for promising that. It is fair towards people who try to answer. A decent answer can have an upvote. If you keep your promise and [edit] all your clarifications into the question it can also have my upvote. And I think then I have kind of proven myself wrong concerning by bet on "No." :-) Have fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own layer system using render targets.

1. Create a texture render target for each layer.
2. Draw to a layer's render target to update it.
3. Every frame, draw each layer to the screen. You still need to clear the final frame beforehand.

It's worth noting that there is a point of diminishing return here. If a layer only contains a few sprites, it's probably cheaper to draw each sprite directly to the screen every frame even if they don't move.

Example:

```c
// Given a renderer
SDL_Renderer *renderer = ...;


// *** Creating the layer ***
SDL_Texture *my_layer = SDL_CreateTexture(
    renderer, 
    SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888,
    SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, 
    screen_width, screen_height);

// To make transparency work (for non-base layers):
SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(my_layer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);


// *** Drawing TO the layer ***
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, my_layer);

// For non-base layers, you want to make sure you clear to *transparent* pixels.
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

// ... Draw to the layer ...


// *** Drawing the layer to the screen / window ***
SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, my_layer, NULL, NULL);
```

You can take this a bit further by creating layers that are larger than `screen_width x screen_height` and use the `srcrect` parameter of `SDL_RenderCopy()` to scroll the layer. With a few background layers, that can be used to get efficient and neat-looking old-school parallax effects.

You will also probably want to encapsulate the notion of a layer into some `Layer` class in C++. Here's a rough starting point:

```cpp
class Layer {
  public:
    Layer(SDL_Renderer *renderer, int w, int h)
      : texture_(SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, w, h),
      , display_{0, 0, 0, 0}
    {
        SDL_GetRendererOutputSize(renderer, &display_.w, &display_.h);
        w = std::min(w, display_.w);
        h = std::min(h, display_.h);

        max_scroll_x = w - display_.w;
        max_scroll_y = h - display_.h;

        SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(texture_, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
    }

    Layer(Layer&& rhs) 
      : texture_(rhs.texture_)
      , display_(rhs.display)
      , max_scroll_x(rhs.max_scroll_x)
      , max_scroll_y(rhs.max_scroll_y) {
        rhs.texture_ = nullptr;
    }

    Layer& operator=(const Layer& rhs) {
      if(texture_) {SDL_DestroyTexture(texture_);}

      texture_ = rhs.texture_;
      display_ = rhs.display_;
      max_scroll_x = rhs.max_scroll_x;
      max_scroll_y = rhs.max_scroll_y;

      rhs.texture_ = nullptr;
    )

    Layer(const Layer& rhs) = delete;
    Layer& operator=(const Layer& rhs) = delete;

    ~Layer() {
      if(texture_) {SDL_DestroyTexture(texture_);}
    }

    // Subsequent draw calls will target this layer
    void makeCurrent(SDL_Renderer* renderer) {
        SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, texture_);
    }

    // Draws the layer to the currently active render target
    void commit(SDL_Renderer* renderer, const SDL_Rect * dstrect=nullptr) {
      SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture_, &display_, dstrect);
    }

    // Changes the offset of the layer
    void scrollTo(int x, int y) {
      display_.x = std::clamp(x, 0, max_scroll_x);
      display_.y = std::clamp(y, 0, max_scroll_y);
    }
private:
    SDL_Texture* texture_;
    SDL_Rect display_;
    int max_scroll_x;
    int max_scroll_y;
};
```

Comment: The mentioning of "old school parallax" alone would have earned my upvote (among other things because it hints at probable follow up issues...). Sadly you can only have one from me. Nice work.